# Knowing which storage device is bottleneck between two devices when transfering data?

Tags: backup, storage, file-transfer

I'm backing up my entire internal storage of my Android device with ADB to the PC storage with OS Windows with Git Bash:

```
adb exec-out "tar -c storage/emulated/0 | gzip" > internal_storage_backup.tar.gz
```

I can't see any log progress or terminal print information, but I know it's doing well because I tested in small directory such as `storage/emulated/0/PDF`.

When I backup entire my internal storage in `storage/emulated/0`, I know it's long progress. Since I don't have any log output, I analyze manually with task manager observing disk progress in `adb.exe` task. I see `3.9MB/s`. I also know that the entire size of my internal storage is about `55G` because I checked it's size first with `adb shell du -sh storage/emulated/0`. With those information, I can use download calculator to estimate the remaining time needed to backup, it's about `4 hours`. I can see my uptime PC as a counter of backup time in task manager because I restart the PC first before doing backup.

We know that the Android doing read operations while Windows doing write operations. But I have no idea which device is bottleneck?

I also need to check the log status during backup, I'm planning pipeline it with `tee` instead of stdout `>`. But I'm not sure the command will be equivalent without affect performance or being wrong command. Also can I set up the block size in tar flags so that it will backups faster?

I'm also thinking the slows operation due to physical media that use USB type A in Windows and MicroUSB in Android. Is there correlation if I change the physical media such as wireless 5Ghz?

Comment: chances are, the bottleneck is the physical connection - although, the `gzip` may also be the issue. Have you tried different compression levels?

Comment: @JaromandaX no I haven't, I forgot to consider compression level.